# Using bitwise operators with (unsigned long) instead of bitfields

Tags: c, bitwise

Here is my solution to Programming Exercise 15-7 from Stephen Prata's *C Primer Plus, 6th Edition*. This problem asks the reader to:

> 15-7
>   Write a program with the same behavior as described in exercise 6, but
>   use an **unsigned long** variable to hold the font information and
>   use the bitwise operators instead of bit members to manage the
>   information.

The previous exercise, referenced in the question, was:

> 15-6
>   Design a bit-field structure that holds the following information:
>
> - Font ID: A number in the range 0--255
> - Font Size: A number in the range 0--127
> - Alignment: A number in the range 0--2 representing the choices Left, Center, and Right
> - Bold: Off (0) or on (1)
> - Italic: Off (0) or on (1)
> - Underline: Off (0) or on (1)
>
> Use this structure in a program that displays the font parameters and uses a looped menu to let the user change parameters....
>   ...
>   [sample interaction here]
>   ...
>   The program should use the **&** operator and suitable masks to ensure that the ID and size entries are converted to the specified range.

A sample run is provided that illustrates the desired formatting for a few interactions. I did not think that this was terribly pertinent to my question, but [here is a Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/ji0AF7RN) to a text file containing the whole of both questions for anyone who is interested. There is an assignment at the beginning of `main()` that sets `font_params` to match the starting point of the sample interaction.

This code works and seems to handle bad inputs acceptably.

I am trying to better understand how to use bitwise operations. I am interested in any comments about the style or robustness of my code, especially as they pertain to its bitwise aspect or how I might have better used bitwise operations and better structured the font parameter bit assignments. I am not certain that I understood the last sentence of the question (15-6) about using "the `&` operator and suitable masks to ensure that the ID and size entries are converted to the specified range." I do use both an `&` operator and a mask, but in my code this is used for a loop test; there is no conversion of an input value.

Any comments are welcome, but I would also be particularly interested in comments about:

- The use of `strtoul()` in the `get_selection()` function to convert an input string to a number
- The use of `strcspn()` in the `get_selection()` function to convert an input string to an `ALIGNMENT` number
- The structure of the user input loop in `get_selection()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/***********************************************************************
 *                    Font Parameter Bit Assignments                   *
 *                                                                     *
 * Property:        ID          SZ         ALN   BLD  ITL  UND         *
 * Offsets:                12         5     3    2    1    0           *
 * Bits:            11111111    1111111    11    1    1    1           *
 * Hex Value:       0xFF000     0xFE0      0x18  0x4  0x2  0x1         *
 *                                                                     *
 ***********************************************************************/

#define UNDERLINE   0x1
#define ITALIC      0x2
#define BOLDFACE    0x4
#define ALIGNMENT   0x18
#define FONT_SZ     0x0FE0
#define FONT_ID     0xFF000
#define UND_OFFSET  0
#define ITL_OFFSET  1
#define BLD_OFFSET  2
#define ALN_OFFSET  3
#define SZ_OFFSET   5
#define ID_OFFSET   12

#define BUFSIZE     5

char * s_gets(char *st, int n);
void show_params(const unsigned long params);
void show_menu(void);
int get_selection(unsigned long *params);

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long font_params = 0;

    /* Assign initial values to font_params: zero initialization  */
    /* gives LEFT alignment with underline, italics, and bold off */
    font_params |= (1 << ID_OFFSET | 12 << SZ_OFFSET);

    do {
        show_params(font_params);
        show_menu();
    } while (get_selection(&font_params));

    puts("Bye!");

    return 0;
}

char * s_gets(char *st, int n)
{
    char *ret_val;
    char *find;

    ret_val = fgets(st, n, stdin);
    if (ret_val) {
        find = strchr(st, '\n');
        if (find)
            *find = '\0';
        else
            while (getchar() != '\n')
                continue;
    }

    return ret_val;
}

void show_params(const unsigned long params)
{
    static char algn[3][10] = {"left   ", "center   ", "right   "};
    static char state[2][4] = {"off", " on"};

    putchar('\n');
    printf("%4s %4s %9s %3s %3s %3s\n",
           "ID", "SIZE", "ALIGNMENT", " B ", " I ", " U ");
    printf("%4lu %4lu %9s %3s %3s %3s\n",
           (params & FONT_ID) >> ID_OFFSET,
           (params & FONT_SZ) >> SZ_OFFSET,
           algn[(params & ALIGNMENT) >> ALN_OFFSET],
           state[(params & BOLDFACE) >> BLD_OFFSET],
           state[(params & ITALIC) >> ITL_OFFSET],
           state[(params & UNDERLINE) >> UND_OFFSET]);
    putchar('\n');
}

void show_menu(void)
{
    puts("f)change font    s)change size    a)change alignment");
    puts("b)toggle bold    i)toggle italic  u)toggle underline");
    puts("q)quit");
}

int get_selection(unsigned long *params)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    char *tailptr;                  // for use with strtoul()
    char options[] = "lcrLCR";      // a string of available options,
    size_t input;                    // in both lower and upper cases

    for (;;) {
        s_gets(buf, 2);

        switch (buf[0]) {
        case 'f':
        case 'F':
            do {
                printf("Enter font ID (0-255): ");
                s_gets(buf, BUFSIZE);
                input = strtoul(buf, &tailptr, 10);
            } while (*tailptr || (input & ~0xFF));
            *params &= ~FONT_ID;    // clear before setting bits
            *params |= input << ID_OFFSET;
            break;

        case 's':
        case 'S':
            do {
                printf("Enter font size (0-127): ");
                s_gets(buf, BUFSIZE);
                input = strtoul(buf, &tailptr, 10);
            } while (*tailptr || (input & ~0x7F));
            *params &= ~FONT_SZ;    // clear before setting bits
            *params |= input << SZ_OFFSET;
            break;

        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            do {
                puts("Select alignment:");
                puts("l)left   c)center   r)right");
                s_gets(buf, 2);
                input = strcspn(options, buf);
            } while (input > strlen(options));
            *params &= ~ALIGNMENT;  // clear before setting bits
            *params |= (input % (strlen(options) / 2) << ALN_OFFSET);
            break;

        case 'b':
        case 'B':
            *params ^= BOLDFACE;
            break;

        case 'i':
        case 'I':
            *params ^= ITALIC;
            break;

        case 'u':
        case 'U':
            *params ^= UNDERLINE;
            break;

        case 'q':
        case 'Q':
            return 0;               // signal to quit
            break;

        default:
            puts("Please enter a valid menu choice.");
            show_menu();
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    return 1;                       // successful selection
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. An `int` may be narrower than an `unsigned long`.  Avoid unexpected behavior by using the correct type.

   ```
   unsigned long font_params = 0;
   // font_params |= (1 << ID_OFFSET | 12 << SZ_OFFSET);
   font_params |= (1ul << ID_OFFSET | 12ul << SZ_OFFSET);
   ```
2. Avoid an infinite loop

   ```
   // while (getchar() != '\n') continue;
   int ch;
   while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) continue;
   ```
3. Consider specifying widths - easier to update/maintain.

   ```
   // printf("%4s %4s %9s %3s %3s %3s\n", "ID", "SIZE", "ALIGNMENT", " B ", " I ", " U ");
   // printf("%4lu %4lu %9s %3s %3s %3s\n", 
   //     (params & FONT_ID) >> ID_OFFSET, 
   //     (params & FONT_SZ) >> ID_OFFSET, ...

   int w[6] = { 4,4,9,3,3,3 };
   printf("%*s %*s %*s ...", w[0], "ID", w[1], "SIZE", w[2], "ALIGNMENT", ...
   printf("%*lu %*lu %*s ...\n", 
       w[0], (params & FONT_ID) >> ID_OFFSET, 
       w[1], (params & FONT_SZ) >> ID_OFFSET, ...
   ```
4. Prefer to use matching types.  Use `unsigned long` for `strtoul()` and `size_t` for `strcspn()`.

   ```
   // size_t input;
   unsigned long input;

   input = strtoul(buf, &tailptr, 10);

   size_t size;

   // input = strcspn(options, buf);
   size = strcspn(options, buf);
   ```
5. Watch out for assuming `~` applies to the width of the target - it is applied to the constant.  What if `unsigned long` was 64-bit, `unsigned` was 32-bit and `FONT_SZ` was `0xFE000000`.  `~FONT_SZ` is an unsigned with the value of `0x01FFFFFF` rather than `0xFFFFFFFF01FFFFFF`, thus masking off the top bits.  Same problem with `~0xFF` anf `~0x7F`.  Better to use `~0xFFul`, etc.

   ```
   unsigned long *params;
   // *params &= ~FONT_SZ; 
   *params &= ~(1ul*FONT_SZ); 
   // or 
   *params |= FONT_SZ; 
   *params ^= FONT_SZ; 
   // or 
   #define FONT_SZ     0x0FE0ul
   ```
6. Unclear why `char buf[BUFSIZE];` is so small (5).  I'd expect a buffer width enough to handle the widest `unsigned long value` and then twice that.  No reason to be stingy in buffer size in user input of a single number.

   ```
   #define ULONG_STR10_LEN (sizeof(unsigned long)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 1) 
   #define BUF_SIZE (ULONG_STR10_LEN*2 + 1 /* \n */ + 1 /* \0 */) 
   char buf[BUF_SIZE];`
   ```

Comment: (1/2) Thanks for the excellent comments @chux, especially (1), (4), and (5). A couple of questions. First, agree about changing to `unsigned long input;` and `size_t size;`. Then, should I change to `*params |= ((1ul * size) % (strlen(options) / 2)) << ALN_OFFSET);`?

Comment: (2/2) Second, I chose a `BUFSIZE` of 5 because the largest valid input read into `buf[]` is a 3 digit number. Choosing 5 allows an input of, e.g., `1000`, which is rejected by the input loop conditions. Choosing 4 would read in a value of `100` if the user entered `1000`, because `s_gets()` would chop off the extra digit. Is the point of your suggestion to use a larger `BUFSIZE` aimed at maintainability and possible future additions to the code?

Comment: @DavidBowling `*params |= ((1ul * size) % (strlen(options) / 2)) << ALN_OFFSET);` does work well as it does the math with the wider of `unsigned long` and `size_t`.  Of course large values of  `strlen(options)` and `size` are not expected.  IMO strange to use a run-time calculation of `strlen(options)` instead of `sizeof (options) - 1`.  Further, rather than code `a,A` and `s,S`, etc., consider  `toupper(buf[0])`.

Comment: @DavidBowling  If input is `"000123\n"` or `"(3 spaces)123\n"`, that results in `input` with a value of 1.  Note that `"-255\n"` also results in 1.  The key issue is that the `do` loops` and `s_gets(buf, BUFSIZE);` are too easy to foul up.   Recommend a function to read input, another function to convert text to number and separate code to test range. `input & ~0x7F` is a non-obvious test to test for `input` on the 0-127 range.  `input <= 127` would make more sense.  Both would likely generate the same code except that later does not have the `~` issue mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: @chux-- Thanks for the `sizeof(options) - 1` tip. Negative values for `input` are converted to `unsigned` by `strtoul()`, and with `BUFSIZE=5` this value should excluded by, e.g., `input & ~0xFF`. But this does seem like too many moving parts, and given your example bad input of `"(3 spaces)123\n"` (which I had not previously considered) which argues in favor of a very large `BUFSIZE`, this seems like a bad design. A large `BUFSIZE` would allow large negative numbers to be entered, which could be converted to unintended in-range values by `strtoul()`.

Comment: I used bitwise tests to test the ranges of the inputs because Prata's question stipulated "use the **&** operator and suitable masks....", otherwise I would have done the more obvious comparison. All together, I can see many design issues now that I was either only vaguely aware of, or completely missing. So it's back to the drawing board for me! Thanks for all of the insightful comments.

Comment: @DavidBowling Yes my "`"-255\n"` also results in 1" was in error.   I consider user input _evil_. and prefer to thwart mischievous users by throughly testing user input, yet allow _reasonable_ extensions like leading white-space, zeros or a `'+'` and trailing white-space, hence my 2x suggestion.  Often these _extra_ characters come from a cut/paste of legitimate data.